# customising django user model is failing

Tags: django

**Hi 
I am trying to customize the django default user. Applying migrations works fine. However I get an error when i try to create a super user. Can you please advise why I get this error?

******************** self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/home/gravityns/PycharmProjects/dev/shop/models.py", line 54, in create_superuser
    user.is_staff = True
AttributeError: can't set attribute

---

```
# accounts.models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password, email):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),

        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, username, password, email):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            password,

        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, email):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            email,
            password

        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


USERNAME_REGEX = '^[a-zA-Z0-9.@+-]*$'

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[
        RegexValidator(regex= USERNAME_REGEX,
                       message = 'Username must be Alphanumeric or any of the following: ". @ + -"')],
                                unique=True

                                )
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user

    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that's built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email'] # Email & Password are required by default.

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.is_admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.is_active
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the normal `is_staff` attribute with your custom property. You need to rename those properties so that they don't clash with the stuff `AbstractBaseUser` already implements. Look at how that class implements `is_staff` and others etc here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L288

Answer (score 0):

You have a field on User model as `User.is_staff` and a `@property` with the same name. So you can't set the property of the model object by `user_instance.is_staff = True`.

You can have [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) as a field or as a class property, not both.

Answer (score 0):

You have unncessarily defined properties for `is_staff`, `is_active` and `is_superuser`. But those are *already* fields, with the exact same name. Therefore, when you try and set `user.is_staff = True`, Python access your property, and tries to "set" that, rather than the field.

There is no reason to do this. The only reason you would need to define those properties is if you want to *disallow* setting the fields themselves. But you don't want to do that. (Alternatively, if you didn't want fields at all, but wanted to base the value on some custom logic - but, again, you wouldn't be able to set them unless you defined a custom setter.)

Remove all three of those properties.